# Where are resources about counting Omer Year round?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, internet, sefirat-ha-omer, mesorah-tradition

My rabbi mentioned there's a custom to count the omer year round. The idea is to travel through all the sefirot for 7 sets of 50 days.

I'm looking for shiurim, texts, etc. that teach on this practice.

I'm also interested in material or apps that help facilitate the count past the official date.

Bonus would be groups or websites that actually do this practice.

Comment: How about Bal Tosif?

Comment: Did you ask your Rabbi for references? I have never ever heard of this

Comment: @MichoelR The Seridei Eish has an interesting chiddush about why Bal Tosif wouldn't apply to Sefira: ולדעתי יש לומר בפשיטות שמצות ספירת העומר אינה מצוה למנות ימים סתם אלא למנות את הימים שבין פסח לשבועות וא"כ אם מנה אחר שבועות לא עשה מצוה כלל ולא שייך על זה בל תוסיף